# attempt to split a string using a regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a big block of text:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM APPLES
GO
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM PEARS TREE
GO
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM FRUITS
...
```

And I'm simply trying to split this text into a list of individual strings based around GO, this works:

```
commandlist = textblock.split("GO")
```

but.. what I'd like to do is use something like:

```
commandlist = textblock.split(r"\bGO\b")
```

because I'm expecting some text to look like:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM GOPATRIOTS
GO
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM PEARS LETITGO
GO SELECT TOP 10 * FROM FRUITS
...
```

but it seems that I can't just shove a regex into split?  Or can I and I'm just missing the way to do so?

Comment: Use `re.split`. So basic, I can't find a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split), not a [string split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
import re
commandlist = re.split(r"\bGO\b", textblock)
```

Or, since you need to split with lines equal to `GO`:

```
commandlist = re.split(r"(?m)^GO$", textblock)
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted.  Code works great.  I'll accept once it let's me.  I love it when I can simply copy/paste the answer over my old line and it just works.